# Running Matlab scripts as ExternalCode Component

Tags: matlab, openmdao

I am trying to use some existing matlab scripts within the openmdao. The external code tutorial is straight forward to follow. However, I encounter some issues when modifying the following example for matlab applications.
original code in tutorial:

```
self.options['command'] = ['python', 'extcode_paraboloid.py', self.input_file, self.output_file]
```

modified code for matlab applications:

```
self.options['command'] = ['matlab', '-nodesktop -r "run Paraboloid.m"', self.input_file, self.output_file]
```

This line is okay to launch matlab. However, other arguments('-r "test.m "') seems have been truncated and can not be interpreted by matlab correctly. The alternative solution I have is to create another .py file for calling os command.

```
os.system('cmd /c "matlab -nodesktop -r "run Paraboloid.m",quit"')
```

Any suggestion on how to call the matlab function directly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking everything up wherever there is a space.

self.options['command'] = `['matlab', '-nodesktop', '-r', '"run Paraboloid.m"', self.input_file, self.output_file]`